# How to unset default git identity

Tags: git, netbeans

does anybody know, where is located something like main config of git?

I use netbeans and when I installed git, it created identity from my username and hostname (stellaireman ). In my home folder wasn't .gitconfig untill I set my new identity, so it created that file. And in that file is just this

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = myemail@gmail.com
```

So I think that somewhere must be some "parent" of this config, where is that stellaireman identity saved (or it is saved somewhere in netbenas?).

I tried `git config --global --unset user.name "stellaireman"` with no success.

My second identity works great but I don't want 2 indentities there. I've made a mistake 3 times yet.

Comment: Did you check in your `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @Jobin I'm not sure what should be there but there is nothing like "stellaireman" or "notebook-ubuntu"

Comment: You might have found something like your name and email id in that file, since you did not, it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git configuration for NetBeans should be found in:

```
~/.netbeans/<your_netbeans_version>/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/git.properties
```

---

#### How to find it:

Try [searching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145306/search-for-a-string-recursively-whilst-in-current-directory) in all the NetBeans configuration files.

First you can check your project's configuration in `/path/to/your/project/nbproject`

```
$ cd /path/to/yout/project/nbproject
$ grep -r -o -i "stellaireman" *
```

If you found nothing, then you can next check the NetBeans main `config` directory.

```
$ cd ~/.netbeans/7.4/config
$ grep -r -o -i "stellaireman" *
```

Of course you need to replace `7.4` by the verison you are using version.